# qbo3 UI: HTML id attribute

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, qbo3

I'm writing UI test scripts for a `qbo3` user interface. I've noted that many HTML `div` tags do not contain an `id` attribute. Can `id` attributes be added to all `div` tags to simplify testing?

Answer (score 0):

The `qbo3` UI standards recommend against relying on `id` tags. Frequently, the same UI widget may be used multiple times within a single HTML page. Once upon a time we replied upon `id` tags, but we found depending on them led to fragility in our JavaScript libraries.

For example, consider the `Loan/Search` panel below:

[image]

In the screen shot above, a basic `Loan/Search` UI allows a pop-out of any `Loan` record. In this example, the `Loan/Summary` UI widget is being rendered twice (for loans `847579790` and `848447735`). If there was a common `id` attribute associated with the `Loan/Summary` widget, it would not be useful, because there can be more than one.

Instead, tests should be designed using the [querySelector functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

| Function | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| `document.querySelector("div.tab-pane")` | Gets the first match. |
| `document.querySelectorAll("div.tab-pane")[1]` | Gets the second match. |

For complicated landing pages, where there may be multiple search and pop-out tabs, you can nest selectors:

```js
// Find the second dashboard tab, and it's first child pane
document.querySelectorAll("div.dashboard")[1].querySelector("div.tab-pane")
```